# Echo command with parenthesis in batch file

Tags: batch-file, echo

What function does the open parenthesis serve in this command?

Why is there no closed parenthesis?

```
>> datatest.csv.TEMP echo(!modified!
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the result of a discussion on [DosTips](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=4554#p4554) about nine years ago.

Your code will redirect the value of `!modified!` to datatest.csv.TEMP or it will print a blank line in that file if the variable is empty.  According to `echo /?`, the official way to display a blank line is to use `echo.`. However, if cmd.exe is somehow able to find an executable with no extension called `echo` (for example, a file in the same directory as the script), that file gets used instead of the regular `echo` command.

A few alternatives to `echo.` were considered, including `echo\`, `echo:`, `echo/` and `echo(`. `echo\` was ruled out in case of a situation where there was a folder called `echo` that contained a file with the same name as whatever was being echoed. `echo/` was ruled out in situations where the string to be displayed started with a `?`, because in the case the help was displayed. `echo:` was ruled out for extremely rare situations where string substitution was being utilized.

Ultimately, `echo(` was ended up with simply because nobody could find a situation where it didn't work. (Later on, there was some speculation that `echo=`, `echo,`, and `echo;` are all safe to use without weird side effects or edge cases. However, if you are trying to display the literal string `/?`, the help for `echo` will be displayed instead.)

The `)` is not included because it will get displayed.

Comment: `echo=`, `echo;` and `echo,` all fail, when `!modified!` expands to `/?`. Then the help of the echo command is displayed

Comment: Thank you both for your notes; my answer had been updated accordingly.

Comment: I always preferred the colon because the `(` irritates users as this question proves. (+1)